# Unit of work in Nhibernate

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am using NHibernate for persistence, but i read somewhere that NHibernate acts as unitofwork container. So do i need to create a separate UnitOfWork implementation. ?

Or continue with Nhibernate's unitofwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create separate UoW implementation.
I suggest you to read  this post: [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2010/07/11/nhibernate-bootstrapper-unitofwork-and-sessionperrequest.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to Martin Fowler, the Unit of Work pattern "maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems."

Nhibernate internally already implements this pattern tracking all the objects has been modified (added,updated,deleted). You don't need to do anything because it already use this pattern itself

just to make this concept clear it is like if for each row of your resultset there is a "magic" column that says if the row has been added,updated or deleted